ACESS DENIED when running .sql file in psql
I encounter an issue when i try to run .sql file in the psql shell(windows)
my code:
tpchr=> \i 'C:/Users/kyyy/Desktop/ts/dbLoadTPCHR.sql';
i got error stating:
psql:C:/Users/kyyy/Desktop/ts/dbLoadTPCHR.sql:1: 
ERROR:  could not open file "C:/Users/kyyy/Desktop/ts/supplier.csv" for reading: Permission denied 
psql:C:/Users/kyyy/Desktop/ts/dbLoadTPCHR.sql:3: 
ERROR:  could not open file "C://Users/kyyy/Desktop/ts/part.csv" for reading: Permission denied

dbLoadTPCHR.sql contains the path to supplier.csv and part.csv that is stored in the same location.
I am trying to load the .sql file inside my table as the csv file contains the inform that was required to insert into the table.

What is the code in dbLoadTPCHR.sql doing?

copy supplier from 'C:/Users/kyyy/Downloads/supplier.csv' HEADER CSV DELIMITER ',';

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

I have faced similar issues, and I recommend trying the following steps, listed in order of significance, hopefully, one will work:

Check File Permissions: Ensure CSV files are not read-only and the
PostgreSQL user has read permissions.
Right-click on the files, select Properties, and check the permissions.
Try using \COPY: Use \COPY instead of COPY for client-side
execution.
Check the PostgreSQL Service User: Verify that the PostgreSQL
service is running under a user with access to the CSV files.
Open psql with Administrator Privileges (if you alrady havent): Run the Command Prompt or
PowerShell as an administrator before launching psql.
Check the Path: Ensure the path and filenames are correct and use
the appropriate path separator (/ or \\).

